# Match everything between certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Wow, I suck at regex

http://regex101.com/r/lM8oX3

```
([*][.]+[*])
```

I'm trying to match text such as this:

```
*hello*
```

Comment: I'm not sure you grok character classes. If you look at the explanation in your link, `[.]` is not doing what you want it to.

Comment: `the literal character *` seems to suggest it's literally matching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try with following regex:

```
(\*[^*]+\*)
```

In your regex you have `[.]` which in fact searches for dots because in `[]` it loses its special context and is treated as a normal character. You should better use `.+` then but it will match also `*` characters. So use my above solution then.

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/lH8fF0)

Comment: Specifically, `*` is a special character in regex that needs escaped with a backslash if you want to test for a literal asterisk.

Comment: @AndrewArnold I've escaped it with `\*`. asterisk in `[*]` does not need to be escaped.

Comment: I know; I was explaining further for OP's benefit.

Answer (score 1):

This will capture

```
var text = "asdfasdf *hello*";
console.log( text.match(/([*][^*]+[*])/)[1]);
```

But that only grabs the first match;

If you want all matches

```
var text = "asdfasdf *hello* asdffdsa  *asdf*";
var matches = text.match(/([*][^*]+[*])/g);

if(matches.length > 1) {
   for(var i=1; i<matches.length; i++) {
       console.log(matches[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: @Max Read the question, at the end

Comment: Well, the question was edited, it used to say "We're in javascript"